# Characters in array are being removed when sorting a string

Tags: java

I am writing a class to print the given string to lexicographical order but in the final method 'reverseOrder()' the array is automatically deleting values from it (I suppose). The method reverseOrder is deleting some characters for selected string such as "dkhc". Thanks

Debugging shows the values are correctly added to the array.

```
public class LexicalOrder {
    static String biggerIsGreater(String w) {
        String finalString = "";
        char[] charArr = w.toCharArray();
        int largestX = -1;
        // Find the largest x such that P[x]<P[x+1].
        // (If there is no such x, P is the last permutation.)
        for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (charArr[i] < charArr[i + 1]) {
                largestX = i;
            }
        }
        if (largestX == -1) {
            finalString = "no answer";
        }
        int largestY = -1;
        if (largestX != -1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < charArr.length; j++) {
                if (charArr[largestX] < charArr[j]) {
                    largestY = j;
                }
            }
            charArr = swap(charArr, largestX, largestY);
            charArr = reverseOrder(charArr, largestX + 1);
            finalString = new String(charArr);
        }
        return finalString;
    }

    // Method to swap characters in index largestX and largestY
    public static char[] swap(char[] a, int largestX, int largestY) {
        char temp = a[largestY];
        a[largestY] = a[largestX];
        a[largestX] = temp;
        return a;
    }

    // Method to reverse the order of the array from the index
    // largestX + 1 to n (n being last element of array)
    public static char[] reverseOrder(char[] a, int index) {
        int step = 0;
        char[] newArr = new char[a.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
            newArr[j] = a[j]; // adding elements to new arr till index=largestX
            System.out.println(newArr[j] = a[j]);
        }
        for (int i = index; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1]; // adding remaining values but with reversing order
            System.out.println(newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1]);
            step++;
        }
        for (char c : newArr)
            System.out.println(c);
        return newArr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(biggerIsGreater("dkhc"));
    }
}
```

What is expected is = hcdk.

But what I get is = hk

I ran the method to check and it clearly adds those elements to the "newArr" array in method 'reverseOrder()' as shown below.

```
0
h
1
c
2
d
3
k
```

Output - hk (and two spaces)

The two characters are replaced by two spaces for some reason.
P.S : I am following the steps mentioned here [link](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-explain-an-algorithm-that-generates-permutations-using-lexicographic-ordering)

Note: It works for some words such as "lmno,dcba,etc"

Comment: Do you have unit tests with simple use cases where it is not working as expected?

Comment: And `c` is before `h` in lexicographical ordering, so I'm not sure I understand the expected output

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry but you're not following. The word "dkhc" is my test case and I know the next lexicographical value is "hcdk". But, the array is simply omitting 'c' and 'd' . The same happens with the word "abdc" where the correct output is "acbd" and I get "acd(and a space character) " so here "b" is omitted and is replaced with a " ". But it runs perfectly for "lmno", "dcba", etc.

Comment: It is probably omitted because you are doing something weird with `step++;` or `newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1]`, and just overwriting the index. Why are you trying to print a variable assignment anyway?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am printing them just to check whether the values are correctly entered in the array at the right position or not, which by the output I mentioned above, shows that it gets added perfectly. What is strange is that it works for most of the words except a few.Had the logic being wrong, it wouldnt have worked for other words, but it does

Comment: _The word "dkhc" is my test case and I know the next lexicographical value is "hcdk"_. But where is "hcdk" in your code?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl that is what the code is supposed to find and the reverseOrder() is the last method of the process which generates the final array(in this case, input being 'dkhc' and expected output being 'hcdk').

Comment: Why doesn't 'h' come after 'd'? Are you sorting character or words? That is important.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I am sorting words. I have a bunch of test cases for which I know the correct answers. This program works for most of the words correctly except a few I've mentioned above. The array 'newArr' is behaving weirdly. Even though the elements are added correctly, it is not getting displayed(i've mentioned this above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have missed is `index++`. In `reverseOrder` method increment `index++` will give you `hcdk` expected output.

```
public static char[] reverseOrder(char[] a, int index) {
        int step = 0;
        char[] newArr = new char[a.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < index; j++) {
            System.out.println(j);
            newArr[j] = a[j]; // adding elements to new arr till index=largestX
            System.out.println(newArr[j] = a[j]);
        }
        for (int i = index; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1]; // adding remaining values
                                                    // but with reversing order
            System.out.println(newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1]);
            step++;index++;
        }
        for (char c : newArr)
            System.out.println(c);
        return newArr;
    }
```

In your case index value is not getting incremented due to which 2 and 3 item in an array are blank.

Comment: You're great! I completely missed that! This line "newArr[index] = a[a.length - step - 1];" was supposed to be "newArr[i] = a[a.length - step - 1];" and you just pointed out the smallest of a mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @pacifistprogrammer Welcome :)

Comment: @pacifistprogrammer if  this answer helped you, can you  upvote it for future reference and visitors